# Can't read usb string descriptor with libusb because of permissions

Tags: python, libusb, pyusb

I just can't do a simple thing as read a string descriptor. Here's the simple code with pyusb wrapper(just for simplicity of code) but the problem remains even with le libsub original library.

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
devs = usb.core.find(find_all=True)
for dev in devs:
    try:
        print usb.util.get_string(dev, 255, dev.iManufacturer)
    except usb.core.USBError:
        pass
```

If I execute this without root permissions i get nothing(all loop iteration raise an exception). If I execute with root permissions I get some string descriptor and some exception. In this case I know the exception is normal because the pipe error means the device does not provide any string descriptor.

The question is: how can I get the string descriptors without the root permissions? The command `lsusb` retrieves all the informations and it does it without the suid bit enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered that problem as well. It seems that pyusb by default opens devices read-write, while `lsusb` opens them read-only, as can be seen in this `$ strace lsusb` extract:

```
...
open("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/uevent", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
...
```

I solved the problem by making all usb devices world-read/writable, but that's definitely not optimal from a security standpoint (keyloggers, etc)...

Comment: Please indulge me; I have only been coding Linux for 17 years. Did you change the permissions for /sys/devices/something/usb/something? or for /dev/bus/usb ? (Rasbian answer preferred, but can work with anything.)

Comment: I changed the permissions for the actual devices, i.e. a `chmod a+rw /dev/bus/usb/*`. I misinterpreted the trace of lsusb at the time, it seems it doesn't use the device descriptors at all, but instead relies on the `/sys` pseudo-fs.

Comment: Tx! And this probably won't help me on Raspbian, because it lets me 'sudo' shamelessly, so I only USB as God anyway, so everything's read-write.

Comment: aaand I had the same bug because I used `usb.util.get_string(dev, 255, dev.iManufacturer)`, like you, instead of the hip, with-it, & modern version, `usb.util.get_string(dev, dev.iManufacturer)`.